# show full image using javascript or jquery from datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, datalist

I am using uplodify upload for uploading the image and binding it in a datalist, I am able to upload and dind the images, but now I want to show the images in a large preview.

The scenario is

by default first image should show in large size, after that when user click on next row then next row image should show in large size till user not click on some other row.

how to do it with the help of javascript or jquery.

please help me soon...

my datalist is

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" onitemcommand="DataList1_ItemCommand" onitemdatabound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" CaptionAlign="Right" CellSpacing="6">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/Controls/ShowImage.ashx?FileName=" +DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilePath") %>'
 OnCommand="Insert_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id").ToString() +";"+Eval("FilePath")%>' />
 <asp:Label ID="lblimagenumber" runat ="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName") %>' ></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken a div

```
    <div id="loadarea" class="imageViewArea">
        <asp:Image ID="imgthumb" runat="server" />
    </div>
```

And on Insert command

```
        Image imgThumb = (Image)this.FindControl("imgthumb");
        imgThumb.ImageUrl = "~/Controls/ShowImage.ashx?FileName=" + ImgName;
```

I am able to show the image

Answer (score 0):

You can have a contianer below or on top of the datalist which contains all the upload images.  Use the js something like this

**Markup**

```
<div id="imagePreview"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$("dataListSelector").find("img").click(function(){

   $("#imagePeview").html("<img src='"this.src"' />");
});
```

**Css** - To show the image preview in big size

```
#imagePeview img
{
  height:400px;//You can either set height or width to an image, it will scale accordingly
}
```

Comment: what is this line  $("#imagePeview").html("<img src='"this.src"' />");
 should i use html file also

Comment: It will append the image tag in the imagePreview div